# Dual Monitor signal issue when Macbook not connected to power

Tags: multiple-monitors, power, macbook

In my current setup, I have 2 [Dell U2715H](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P0EQD1Q) monitors plugged into my Mid 2015 Macbook Pro laptop via 2 mini DP cables. Additionally, I have a Corsair k95 platinum keyboard plugged into the Macbook via usb and a Logitech MX Master 2s connected via bluetooth.

I like to have my Macbook lid closed in this setup, and when connected to power through the AC adapter, the setup works fine and as expected. The problem occurs when the Macbook lid is closed and not connected to power. The 2 monitors do not detect a signal.

Is it possible to operate the above setup without the laptop connected to power?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by macOS' power settings. Per default, when you close the lid on your MacBook is put to sleep.
See: The requirements for [closed-display mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834) are per Apple:

> Requirements for closed-display mode
>   To use closed-display mode with your Mac notebook, you need:
>
> - An AC power adapter
> - An external keyboard and mouse or trackpad, either USB or wireless
> - A USB-C to USB adapter if you're using a USB mouse or keyboard with MacBook (2015 and later) or MacBook Pro (2016 and later)
> - An external display or projector

Can you override the default behavior using `pmset`

To disable wake/sleep on lid state:

```
sudo pmset -a lidwake 0
```

or undo this `sudo pmset -a lidwake 1`

However, the setting is not recommended don't recommend it since your laptop would stay awake regardless - whether the lid is closed or not.   But you can still put the laptop to sleep manually, i.e. the power button, or via UI.

Comment: Tried your above method, but unfortunately did not change anything. Any suggestions on a follow up or to check how to manipulate above strategy? Wondering if having the macbook plugged into power is unavoidable while lid is closed...